# Angular Nrwl Nx Data Persistence with non-class Actions

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Is it possible to use non-class-based actions with Nx Data Persistence? I could not find anything in the docs. This here is what I tried so far:

```
run: (action, state) => {
      const booking: Booking = action.booking;
      return this.httpClient.post<FirebasePostResponse>('https://foo/bar.json', booking).pipe(
        map((res, err) => {
          return bookingsAddOneSuccess({booking});
        })
      );
    },
```

which is giving me a type mismatch error. I guess a workaround would be to use `@Effect({dispatch: false})` and dispatch from the run method yourself without returning anything. But perhaps there is a better way, without misusing Effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgRx now features action creators:

```js
export const addOne('[Bookings] Add One', props<{ booking: BookingsEntity }>());

export const addOneSuccess('[Bookings] Add One Success', props<{ booking: BookingsEntity }>());
```

Which work fine with Nx's Data Persistence functions:

```js
addOne = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(BookingsActions.addOne),
    pessimisticUpdate({
      // provides an action
      run: ({ booking }) => {
        // update the backend first, then dispatch an action
        // that will update the client side
        return this.httpClient.post<FirebasePostResponse>(
          'https://foo/bar.json',
          booking
        ).pipe(
          map((res, err) => {
            return BookingsActions.bookingsAddOneSuccess({ booking });
          })
        );
      },
      onError: ({ booking }, error) => {
        // we don't need to undo the changes on the client side.
        // we can dispatch an error, or simply log the error here and return `null`
        return null;
      },
    })
  )
);
```